# How could apps start which are stopped by the setting panel when my device has connected to wifi in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I got to know that app is in **stopped** state when either 1. never launched after installed. 2. force-stop by user in the setting panel.
When app in the **stopped** state, app can't receive broadcast with only tag "FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES", such as the `BOOT_COMPLETED` and `wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED`.
The problem i encount: I force-stop all the apps in the setting panel, when I connecting wifi, after a while, some apps are running there.
What confuses is why the **stopped** app can receive broadcast or something, is there anything i missed?  Thanks.

Comment: Answer is in the [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: what cited in the question is *broadcast*, nothing to with *service*. and i have already read it but "bound service" and "aidl"

Comment: *I force-stop all the apps*, then... *some apps are running there.* some of those apps would have a **service** that has, more than likely, a broadcast receiver, hence they appear to be still running.

Comment: That is the point, a *force-stop* app is in the **stopped** state, it can't accept broadcast without flag "FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES", and I read it that system broadcast doesn't carry this flag. So why these apps able to start?